How can I stop my younger cat from chasing my older cat?
Pretty desperate here. I have a 3 year old cat, Capitaine, who keeps chasing my 8 year old cat, Gigi. We have tried everything to make him change this habit. It happens more often at sunset. He will often chase him around the appartment and jump on him and even bite and pull his fur. He is not a bad cat but this behavior is unacceptable. We have been introducing them since January 2024. We tried playing with him, toys , hiding treats in the house for him to look for, etc. We talked with a veterinarian, we tried medication, which helped a little but we cannot make him understand that he need to find another toy then his brother. Will this get better with time or as he ages?
Gigi is my girlfriend's cat and she is getting pretty tired of his behavior which I understand. Please help

My honest opinion is that your situation right now is not salvageable. Capitaine sees himself as the "owner" of the apartment and Gigi as a trespasser who needs to be chased away.
The easy way out: give one of them away. I assume you've already ruled this out, otherwise you wouldn't ask here. If you want to keep both cats, you need to change their situation drastically.
Most important question: are they both neutered? If not, there's no hope of them ever living peacefully together (since they already started fighting). You need to neuter at least Capitaine, but probably both of them. Sexually intact tomcats are extremely territorial and fight all other intact males. The only way around this I know of is to let 2 brothers of the same litter grow up together without any female, but even that is no guarantee.
The alternative: Keep them separated at all times. Decide which cats get to live where - typically one in the living room and one in the bedroom and keep them there. Keep the doors closed and keep each cat in his new territory. If possible, keep the doors to adjacent rooms open, but don't let their territories overlap. If this is not possible because of the layout of the apartment, create a time table when each cat gets free range and the other has to stay in "his" room.
You should probably keep this arrangement for a few months before starting the whole introduction process again. Their relationship right now is so strained that they need to reset it.

unfortunately, sundown and daybreak is when kittens and younger cats are more active with that said why don’t you just find a safe room for your older cat with everything that Gigi needs a.k.a. food, water litter box and at that time of night just place  her in that room and play with the other cat get some of his energy out!!!! I would also feed it a small can of food after expelling some of his energy this will help calm him .Once this routine is established you will find that he won’t pay much attention to GiGi once she is Slowly introduced back around that time of night. In the meantime, I’m sure Gigi will appreciate the rest away from the shenanigans of her brother.
